# How to display settings menu on click of settings icon?

Tags: android

1. Settings menu is created in activity_settingsmenu.xml .
2. Settings icon is in activity_settingsicon.xml .

How to link both the activities so that on clicking settings icon, the settings menu will be displayed?

---

(Just started learning Android Application development - beginner)

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: Inflate the same menu in both activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: you want show menu option along with icon ?
then you try below code
`<item
        android:id="@+id/business"
        android:label="drawable/your_image"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/business"
        app:showAsAction="never" />`

Comment: You gotta use a [Dialog Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create menu folder in res.Create xml for e.g menu_main.xml under menu folder.

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="in.nfnlabs.stormit.Parent">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

If u want to add icon, use this:

```xml
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
    android:title="@string/action_settings"      
    android:icon="@drawable/bookmark"
    android:orderInCategory="100" 
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

In your activity class inflate the menu like below:

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.addnew, menu);
    return true;
}
```

If you want to perform actions in menu this can be achieved by [onOptionsItemSelected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem))

```java
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int i = item.getItemId();
    if(i==R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bookmark", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```