# How to display menu item in action bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

menu item is not appearing in action bar. I am trying this code on API 19, kitkat 4.4 
using this XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:title="Sign out"
        android:id="@+id/iSignout"
        android:icon="@drawable/signout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:title="My Profile"
        android:id="@+id/iEditProfile"/>
    <item
        android:title="Edit Profile"
        android:id="@+id/iMyProfile"/>
</menu>
```

and

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: To answer your additional question: Like you can always check [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html), `orderInCategory` defines the importance of the item, so it affects the order of the items. It is possible to apply multiple sources of items on one menu, so this defines how the are sorted.

Comment: thanks alot... its working :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:title="Sign out"
        android:id="@+id/iSignout"
        android:icon="@drawable/signout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:title="My Profile"
        android:id="@+id/iEditProfile"/>
    <item
        android:title="Edit Profile"
        android:id="@+id/iMyProfile"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `android:showAsAction="always"` with `app:showAsAction="always"`

Answer (score 0):

Try
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"

Answer (score 0):

[How to display settings menu on click of settings icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41715697/how-to-display-)           settings-menu-on-click-of-settings-icon/41716117#41716117